# How can I force HTTP-only mode in the C# AWS SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3

It looks like there used to be an option in the AmazonS3Config class to specify the communication protocol to use, but I don't see that anymore.  Where did it go?

I'm trying to do some benchmarking, and one of the things I want to test is HTTP vs HTTPS.  Since a lot of our objects are fairly small (less than 512k), I'm wondering if the HTTPS handshaking is contributing to our slowness in uploading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration is now called `UseHttp`. It's in the 'Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig' class that is the base for all of the client-specific config classes.

```
var config = new AmazonS3Config { UseHttp = true, ... };
var client = new AmazonS3Client(config);
```

This works for all clients (unless they don't support http. You can still set it, but it will be ignored).